# Limpìar cache sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de limpiar cache de mi motor de bases de datos en sql server, alguna idea de como hacerlo sin riesgos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con el siguiente comando.

```
  DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
```

Esta linea lo que hace es eliminar todo el cache que no esta siendo utilizado.

referencia [Limpiar memoria cache en SQL Server](https://aprendebi.wordpress.com/2016/11/10/limpiar-memoria-cache-en-sql-server-dbcc-freeproccache-transact-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar estos comandos:

Para borrar todos los planes de memoria de caché:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

Para vaciar la caché de los datos:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

Comment: Revisar [answer],saludos